# How to pass string to a function in VBA?

Tags: function, ms-access, vba

I am trying to pass different table names as strings so they can be used in a function that will export the table I specify to an excel spreadsheet. I cannot get it to work because when I try to do the "DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet" command, it says that it does not recognize "table_name". I thought that if I passed a string name with the name of the table that it would work, but apparently it doesn't. Am I passing the string wrong, or am I not allowed to do this? Also, what type of excel spreadsheet should I export it as? I didn't see the differences between the different types.

```
Public Function NAME_FILE(table_name As String)

Dim strName As String
Dim strLocation As String
Dim strXLS As String
Dim strFinalName As String

strName = InputBox("What do you want to name the file?", "File Name")
strLocation = "C:\folder1\"
strXLS = ".xls"
strFinalName = strLocation & "" & strName & "" & strXLS

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "table_name", strFinalName, True

End Function

Public Function EXPORT_PRODUCT_CODE()
Dim T_PRODUCT_CODE As String

NAME_FILE (T_PRODUCT_CODE)

End Function

Public Function EXPORT_CAMPAIGN_CODE()
Dim T_CAMPAIGN_CODE As String

NAME_FILE (T_CAMPAIGN_CODE)
End Function
```

Comment: Regarding the choices for spreadsheet type, open the Access help topic for the *DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Method* and find the link which takes you to the *AcSpreadSheetType Enumeration*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*table_name* is the name of the parameter you're using to hold the name of a table.  So, for `TransferSpreadsheet`, do not use quotes around that name.  Then you will be feeding `TransferSpreadsheet` the name of the table instead of the literal text *"table_name"*.

```vb
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
    table_name, strFinalName, True
```

IOW, you want to handle *table_name* the same as you did for your *strFinalName* variable --- don't enclose the name with quotes.

Also you have 2 other functions which call your `NAME_FILE()` function.  Each of those creates a local string variable which is passed to `NAME_FILE()`.  However you don't assign a table name to either of those variables, so the result is the same as `NAME_FILE("")`.  Then, when you hit the `TransferSpreadsheet` statement, you have an empty string (`""`) for the *TableName* parameter which causes Access to complain *"The action or method requires a Table Name argument."*

Comment: Thanks again for helping HansUp! I tried what you said, but I then got this error message "The action or method requires a Table Name argument."

Comment: What do you see if you add `MsgBox(table_name)` to the `NAME_FILE` function?

Comment: That will be a problem!  Give the function the name of a table when you call it.

Comment: I just got it to work. I did NAME_FILE("T_PRODUCT_CODE") in my EXPORT_PRODUCT_CODE function. Thanks again HansUp!!